# show function usinng jquery does not open the pop up in firefox

Tags: jquery

The open function below takes a div element adds a class "showModal" and then shows the pop up.This code works fine in chrome and IE browser, but in firefox the pop up does not show up on page load. But when I add break point to the lines within the open function, the pop up shows in firefox. Does jquery show function have some known issue in firefox

```
 Plugin.prototype = {

    open: function(element) {
            var $newEl = $(element).clone(true);
            var $contain = $mWrap.find('#SNIModal_Content').empty();
            $newEl = $newEl.appendTo($contain);
            $mWrap.addClass('showModal').show();
            return $newEl[0];
    }
    };
```

Comment: figured out the cause of the issue, the element had style display: none in css and enabling using show() did not work in firefox. The fix was to remove the display:none on the css or using .css('display', 'block') instead of show().

Answer (score 0):

figured out the cause of the issue, the element had style display: none in CSS and enabling using `show()` did not work in Firefox. The fix was to remove the display:none on the CSS or using `.css('display', 'block')` instead of `show()`.